# How can I make this callback function only be called once? after my For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

The context is that I am trying to retrieve a list of records called `Posts` from a `firebase` database, first above I have gathered all the 'subcribed clubs' the user is in and put them in the array `SubscribedClubsList` in this instance the array contains the values `ALT5` and `BSM14` which are the keynames for the Clubs in the database.

[image]

the first `for loop` will go through all the items in `SubscribedClubList`

In my database the clubs have a designated space where they store `posts` as seen in the image. The function `getData` iterates through each post the club has made and stores it in the array `postArr`, after that I then `callback` the `array postArr` as I want to use this list of stored `posts` to display in a table on my webpage.

As you can see in the database screenshot both of the `subscribed` societies have 3 posts each so the size of `postArr` is 6

However when I log it at my bottom on my code it and log a post from the 1st Club list like `console.log(arrNew[2])` it will log it twice, such as

`{Post: "meet and greet on friday", Timestamp: 1523298517138}
 {Post: "meet and greet on friday", Timestamp: 1523298517138}`

and when I log any post from the 2nd Club such as `console.log(arrNew[5])` or console.log[3] it will log similar to this:

`undefined
{Post: "welcome", Timestamp: 1523359646325}`

How can I stop it logging twice like this and have the one time it logs be the full list as intended.

I assume it is because the `callback` runs after the first iteration of the first `for loop` and returns the first 3 posts from the 1st club, then returns the 6 posts on the 2nd iteration.

```
        function getPosts(callback){
        var x = 0; 
        var postArr = [];

        for (var y = 0 ; y < SubscripedClubsList.length ; y++){

         var ref = firebase.database().ref('ClubPosts').child(SubscripedClubsList[y]);
         ref.on('value', getData, errData);

        function getData(data){
            var posts = data.val();
            var keys = Object.keys(posts);
            for (var i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++){
                var k = keys[i];

                postArr[x] = posts[k];
                x++;

            }

                callback(postArr);



        }

        function errData(err){
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(err);
        }

     }

    }

   getPosts(function (arrNew){
    console.log(arrNew[2]);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple if condition around callback like this.

`if(y==SubscripedClubsList.length-1){
callback(postArr);
}`

I think, this should solve the problem as the callback will get called only on the last loop.

Comment: It isn't logging anything now

Comment: Check if the variable y is accessible inside the function. If not we gotta figure out a way to pass into the function.

Comment: it does retrieve y and when I changed your if statement to `if(y==SubscripedClubsList.length){
console.log(y);
}` it logged '2'

Comment: perhaps I put your solution in the wrong place, I had places where the original callback was

Comment: May be. I answered based  on the question you posted. Did it finally work?

Comment: No it didn't sorry. To help you answer I checked to see the value of `y` by logging it in the function `getData` the result was that logged `2` in all  6 iterations (as there are 6 `posts`). I then logged `y` in the first `for` loop and it logged `0` in the first iteration and then `1` in the second iteration